# Draw Primitives with Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity

I would like to be able to draw primitives in unity 2d to define my game objects. I have tried the following example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Material mat;
    private Vector3 startVertex;
    private Vector3 mousePos;
    void Update() {
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            startVertex = new Vector3(mousePos.x / Screen.width, mousePos.y / Screen.height, 0);

    }
    void OnPostRender() {
        if (!mat) {
            Debug.LogError("Please Assign a material on the inspector");
            return;
        }
        GL.PushMatrix();
        mat.SetPass(0);
        GL.LoadOrtho();
        GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
        GL.Color(Color.red);
        GL.Vertex(startVertex);
        GL.Vertex(new Vector3(mousePos.x / Screen.width, mousePos.y / Screen.height, 0));
        GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();
    }
    void Example() {
        startVertex = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

However I cannot find information on setting the Materical element of a game object anywhere. I am trying to create a simple 2d game using GL to draw the sprites instead of textures. My questions are:

- What is the material object reference used for and is this required for unity 2d games?
- Is using GL the easiest way to draw primitives in unity?

Comment: Do you want to draw the outline of these primitives using lines? Or fill them in with a texture?

Comment: I would like to draw the outline with lines. I might want to fill them with a texture at a later time, but not right now.

Answer (score 1):

Aras Pranckevičius explained this issue, more clearly than I am able to, in a [post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/gl-lines.7338/#post-54746) on the Unity Forums:

> GL immediate drawing functions use whatever is the "current material" set up right now. The material controls how the rendering is done (blending, textures, etc.) So unless you explicitly set it to something before using GL draw functions, the material can happen to be anything. Also, if you call any other drawing commands from inside GL drawing code, they can set material to something else, so it's not good to mix them.

Your `mat` variable is just a public field so you could:

1. Assign a value using the inspector.
2. Load one of the standard materials e.g.

   `mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Diffuse"));`
3. Define a custom Shader in code (Aras' example).

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

   public class LineSample : MonoBehaviour {

       static Material lineMaterial;

       private static void CreateLineMaterial() {
           if( !lineMaterial ) {
               lineMaterial = new Material( "Shader \"Lines/Colored Blended\" {" +
                   "SubShader { Pass { " +
                   "    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha " +
                   "    ZWrite Off Cull Off Fog { Mode Off } " +
                   "    BindChannels {" +
                   "      Bind \"vertex\", vertex Bind \"color\", color }" +
                   "} } }" );
               lineMaterial.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
               lineMaterial.shader.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
           }
       }

       public void OnPostRender() {
           CreateLineMaterial();
           lineMaterial.SetPass( 0 );
           GL.Begin( GL.LINES );
           GL.Color( new Color(1f, 1f ,1f ,0.5f) );
           GL.Vertex3( 0, 0, 0 );
           GL.Vertex3( 1, 0, 0 );
           GL.Vertex3( 0, 1, 0 );
           GL.Vertex3( 1, 1, 0 );
           GL.Color( new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f) );
           GL.Vertex3( 0, 0, 0 );
           GL.Vertex3( 0, 1, 0 );
           GL.Vertex3( 1, 0, 0 );
           GL.Vertex3( 1, 1, 0 );
           GL.End();
       }
   }
   ```

Once you have a material defined calling [`SetPass()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetPass.html) assigns it as current.

---

If familiar with OpenGL Immediate Mode this approach is pretty straight forward, but if you later decide that you would like to texture your primitives I would recommend using a MeshRenderer with a custom mesh.  Morten Nobel has published a [tutorial](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2010/12/25/procedural-generated-mesh-in-unity/) on using this approach with 3D meshes his blog. The same approach can be used create a plane of arbitrary shape.